# SignalR doesn't work with Azure Mobile Service .NET backend Basic Tier

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-mobile-services

I've been having issues with SignalR when upgrading my mobile service backend to the Basic tier from the free tier. The errors I keep getting from the client are:

```
01:48:22.5196201 - null - ChangeState(Disconnected, Connecting)
01:48:22.7613718 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - WS Connecting to: wss://dev-sbp-ct.azure-mobile.net/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=webSockets&connectionData=[{"Name":"scthub"}]&connectionToken=EMKwYVGq5cNqAzwXpHQzzKuu3Vq9q24%2B5SPCZKUBEPB8%2BF9jJSp4TDEpB9fO5vFn7Bo0WootRAHhY9R54jSIMQnkExGhwJ4YM1Kyzydd%2BrlTmuNROnI%2BB73t6OTX54f%2F
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
01:48:27.7842438 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport webSockets. System.TimeoutException: Transport timed out trying to connect
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.OperationCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
01:48:27.8032454 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - SSE: GET https://dev-sbp-ct.azure-mobile.net/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=serverSentEvents&connectionData=[{"Name":"scthub"}]&connectionToken=EMKwYVGq5cNqAzwXpHQzzKuu3Vq9q24%2B5SPCZKUBEPB8%2BF9jJSp4TDEpB9fO5vFn7Bo0WootRAHhY9R54jSIMQnkExGhwJ4YM1Kyzydd%2BrlTmuNROnI%2BB73t6OTX54f%2F
01:48:27.8847691 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - WS: OnClose()
01:48:27.9207782 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - SSE: OnMessage(Data: initialized)
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
01:48:32.8109745 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport serverSentEvents. System.TimeoutException: Transport timed out trying to connect
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
01:48:32.8209762 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - LP Connect: https://dev-sbp-ct.azure-mobile.net/signalr/connect?clientProtocol=1.4&transport=longPolling&connectionData=[{"Name":"scthub"}]&connectionToken=EMKwYVGq5cNqAzwXpHQzzKuu3Vq9q24%2B5SPCZKUBEPB8%2BF9jJSp4TDEpB9fO5vFn7Bo0WootRAHhY9R54jSIMQnkExGhwJ4YM1Kyzydd%2BrlTmuNROnI%2BB73t6OTX54f%2F
The thread 0x111c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
01:48:37.8628968 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Auto: Failed to connect to using transport longPolling. System.TimeoutException: Transport timed out trying to connect
01:48:37.8709058 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Disconnected
01:48:37.8714054 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Transport.Dispose(d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20)
01:48:37.8719060 - d8633b78-1b64-49e0-8013-973986405a20 - Closed
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I've tried using Signalr Client version 2.1.1 but it still didn't help. When I switch the Mobile Service back to the Free tier it all starts working. Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is answered here in the [Mobile Services Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7289636c-59f0-4bec-88e5-bf3f0b2f5814/signalr-doesnt-work-with-basic-tier-of-azure-mobile-service-net-backend?forum=azuremobile).

Summary: if you scale your mobile service to Basic or Standard, Mobile Services uses Service Bus as a SignalR backplane. If the Notification Hub namespace is deleted, you will see this error. To fix, go to the Push tab of your Mobile Service and select "Recreate Notification Hub"